# svn commit failed as they refer to the same URL

Tags: tortoise-svn

I am getting the following error -

```
            Command: Commit  
            Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
            Error: Cannot commit both   
            Error: '<path>\myfilename.java'   
            Error: and   
            Error: '<path>\myfilename.java'   
            Error: as they refer to the same URL  
            Finished!:
```

when I try to commit even a small change to myfilename.java to SVN. I am using Tortoise SVN.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

In one of the paths, delete the ".svn" folders. And then do an update on your working directory and commit. Somehow the metadata ( in .svn ) got mixed between the two paths.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a config file that was shared between two projects but I had updated the file (with the same changes) in both projects.

SVN can't commit as it thinks there are two different sets of changes to be commited to the same file.

So I reverted one of the copies and then I was able to commit.